# How to create compound auto_increment columns, one of them group-wise

Tags: mysql, sql

Parent Table - sectionId is the primary key

```
|    sectionId     |     Name   |
|       1          |  Section1  |  
|       2          |  Section2  |  
|       3          |  Section3  |
```

Child Table - Composite key (sectionId and valueId)

```
|   sectionId    |     valueId    |      LectureValue        |
|    1           |      1         |        somevalue1        |  
|    1           |      2         |        somevalue2        |  
|    2           |      1         |        somevalue3        |  
|    2           |      2         |        somevalue4        |  
|    1           |      3         |        somevalue5        |  
|    2           |      3         |        somevalue6        |  
|    3           |      1         |        somevalue7        |  
|    3           |      2         |        somevalue8        |
```

I want the valueId to be filled based on the sectionId like

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
```

If sectionId 2 comes then

```
2-1
2-2
```

If I insert the any sectionId for first time the corresponding valueID should be as 1 and then the sequence should continue

Is there any possible way to do it in MYSQL itself?

Comment: How do you insert records into the ChildTable?

Comment: By using manual java program i identify the value of the valueId now i inserting the child table records.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store values like `2-1`. Instead, when you need it like that, do

```
SELECT CONCAT(sectionId, '-', valueId) AS my_fancy_valueId FROM table...
```

Then you can achieve this with tables using the MyISAM storage engine. Caveat is, that it doesn't (yet) support foreign keys or transactions.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
```

> Which returns:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

> In this case (when the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of a multiple-column index), AUTO_INCREMENT values are reused if you delete the row with the biggest AUTO_INCREMENT value in any group. This happens even for MyISAM tables, for which AUTO_INCREMENT values normally are not reused.